# Count total and count having in the same query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

is there a way to get a total count of rows per {id, date} and the count > 1 per {id, date, columnX} in the same query?

For example, having such a table:

```
 id         date         columnX
1        2017-04-20         a
1        2017-04-20         a
1        2017-04-18         b
1        2017-04-17         c
2        2017-04-20         a
2        2017-04-20         a
2        2017-04-20         c
2        2017-04-19         b
2        2017-04-19         b
2        2017-04-19         b
2        2017-04-19         b
2        2017-04-19         c
```

As the result, I wanna get the following table:

```
id         date       columnX         count>1    count_total  
1        2017-04-20       a              2            2
2        2017-04-20       a              2            3
2        2017-04-19       b              4            5
```

I tried to do it with partition by but receive weird results. I've heard Rollup function might be used but it seems like it's applicable only in legacy SQL, which is not the option for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select id, date, columnx, cnt,
       (case when cnt > 1 then cnt else 0 end) as cnt_gt_1,
       total_cnt
from (select id, date, columnx, count(*) as cnt
             sum(count(*)) over (partition by id, date) as total_cnt
      from t
      group by id, date, columnx
     ) x
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! Solves the issue. Though, had to add another query (select * from your query where cnt > 1 ) , since 'where cnt > 1' in your query was removing those from the Total as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
SELECT
  id,
  date,
  data.columnX columnX,
  data.count_ count_bigger_1,
  count_total
FROM(
  SELECT
    id,
    date,
    ARRAY_AGG(columnX) data,
    COUNT(1) count_total
  FROM
    `your_table_name`
  GROUP BY
    id, date
  ),
UNNEST(ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT columnX, count(1) count_ FROM UNNEST(data) columnX GROUP BY columnX HAVING count(1) > 1)) data
```

You can test it with simulated data:

```
WITH data AS(
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2017-04-20' AS date, 'a' AS columnX UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2017-04-20' AS date, 'a' AS columnX UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2017-04-18' AS date, 'b' AS columnX UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2017-04-17' AS date, 'c' AS columnX UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, '2017-04-20' AS date, 'a' AS columnX UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, '2017-04-20' AS date, 'a' AS columnX UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, '2017-04-20' AS date, 'c' AS columnX UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, '2017-04-19' AS date, 'b' AS columnX UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, '2017-04-19' AS date, 'b' AS columnX UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, '2017-04-19' AS date, 'b' AS columnX UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, '2017-04-19' AS date, 'b' AS columnX UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, '2017-04-19' AS date, 'c' AS columnX  
)

SELECT
  id,
  date,
  data.columnX columnX,
  data.count_ count_bigger_1,
  count_total
FROM(
  SELECT
    id,
    date,
    ARRAY_AGG(columnX) data,
    COUNT(1) count_total
  FROM
    data
  GROUP BY
    id, date
  ),
UNNEST(ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT columnX, count(1) count_ FROM UNNEST(data) columnX GROUP BY columnX HAVING count(1) > 1)) data
```

This solution avoids the analytical function (which can be quite expensive depending on the input) and scales well to large volumes of data.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to add into your example two more below rows

```
1        2017-04-20         x
1        2017-04-20         x
```

and check what solutions in two previous answers will give you:
It will be something like below:

```sql
id         date       columnX         count>1    count_total  
1        2017-04-20       a              2            4
1        2017-04-20       x              2            4
2        2017-04-20       a              2            3
2        2017-04-19       b              4            5
```

Notice two rows for id=1 and date=2017-04-20 and both having count_total=4
I am not sure if this is what you want - even though you might not even considered this scenario in your question

Anyway, I feel that to support more generic case like above your expectation of output should of be like below

```sql
Row id  date        x.columnX   x.countX    count_total  
1   1   2017-04-20  x           2           4    
                    a           2        
2   2   2017-04-20  a           2           3    
3   2   2017-04-19  b           4           5
```

where x is repeated field and each value represents respective columnX with its count

Below query does exactly this

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT id, date,
  ARRAY(SELECT x FROM UNNEST(x) AS x WHERE countX > 1) AS x,
  count_total
FROM (
  SELECT id, date, SUM(countX) AS count_total,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<columnX STRING, countX INT64>(columnX, countX) ORDER BY countX DESC) AS X    
  FROM (
    SELECT id, date, 
      columnX, COUNT(1) countX
    FROM  `yourTable`
    GROUP BY id, date, columnX
  )
  GROUP BY id, date
  HAVING count_total > 1
)
```

you can play/test it with dummy data from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourTable` AS(
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2017-04-20' AS date, 'a' AS columnX UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2017-04-20', 'a' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2017-04-20', 'x' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2017-04-20', 'x' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2017-04-18', 'b' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2017-04-17', 'c' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-04-20', 'a' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-04-20', 'a' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-04-20', 'c' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-04-19', 'b' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-04-19', 'b' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-04-19', 'b' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-04-19', 'b' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-04-19', 'c'  
)
SELECT id, date,
  ARRAY(SELECT x FROM UNNEST(x) AS x WHERE countX > 1) AS x,
  count_total
FROM (
  SELECT id, date, SUM(countX) AS count_total,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<columnX STRING, countX INT64>(columnX, countX) ORDER BY countX DESC) AS X    
  FROM (
    SELECT id, date, 
      columnX, COUNT(1) countX
    FROM  `yourTable`
    GROUP BY id, date, columnX
  )
  GROUP BY id, date
  HAVING count_total > 1
)
```